# FileNotFoundException while trying to import URI that contains emoji

Tags: android, import, uri, decode

I wrote some code in my android app to import files.
It is working well when i import a file like `foo.bar` but it's not when i try to import a file that contains an emoji like `foo.bar`

Each time I get a **FileNotFoundException** when i try to use *openFileDescriptor* method from contentResolver...

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = mActivity.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mImportUri, "r");
```

Here is the value for **mImportUri**:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ffoo%20%F0%9F%98%AD.bar
```

I assume openFileDescriptor does not support `%20%F0%9F%98%AD` in the URI but i don't know how to fix it ??

**edit:**

a simple use case. Only 1 button and one TextView to get the result.
When i try to get `foo.bar` it si working -> result = OK but when i select `foo.bar` result is KO -> so i got an exception.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public final static int IMPORT_NEBO_REQUEST = 0;
public TextView resText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    findViewById(R.id.import_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}    

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");

    //This will start the appropriate app able to pick a file
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_NEBO_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMPORT_NEBO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            resText.setText("OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resText.setText("KO");
        }

    }
}
```

**Not working** on Samsung GTab 12pce -> Android 5.0.2
**Working** on Samsung GTab 3 -> Android 7 
**Not working** on Huawei M2 -> Android 5.1.1
**Not working** on Nvidia sheld -> Android 6
**Working** on OnePlus 3 -> Android 7.1.1

Is someone could help me?
François

Comment: `Here is the value for mImportUri:` Is mImportUri an Uri or a String instance? If it was an Uri than `mImportUri.toString()` should deliver that content scheme. Further you are not showing us where you get that uri/string from. Please start at the beginning.

Comment: it is an URI. I get it after having select a file in the browser (via the launch of an activity `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) and retrieve data in onActivityResult (`intent.getData()`)

Comment: I still dont know enough. Please show how Uri mImportUri is instantiated.

Comment: Especially for you i created some files with emoijs in their file name and i can open them using openFileDescriptor(). So what are you doing?

Comment: i have just modified the question

Comment: `mImportController.doImport(data.getData());` Sorry but  we cannot see what you are doing with data.getData().

Comment: Why dont you just put all code in onActivityResult? Then we can see what you are doing. You even dont need to put all code as only the opening of the filedescripter will do if that is the culprit. Just post code that demonstrates the problem. Dont bother us with your classes and so. They obscure what is happening.

Comment: Can it be that you did not ask for READ permission in manifest file? Or for Marshmellow and above no runtime permissions implemented? Just an idea.

Comment: nop i add all needed permissions

Comment: Your code looks ok. I give up.

Comment: You could try to open an InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()); And use that for the FileChannel instead of the FileInputStream. Give it a try ;-).

Comment: And put the openFileDescriptor() code line in onActivityResult just for a test.

Comment: So all works. Only the emoijs bring trouble. Strange. On which Android version?

Comment: `[check permissions & put it in an async process]` ???? We again do not know what happens and if that influences your problem.

Comment: `mActivity.getContentResolver()` Is mActivity the activity from the onActivityResult() ? Oh what do i have to ask a lot... we dont see what you are doing... put that code directly in onActivityResult()!!!

Comment: ok i just created a sample with the smallest code as possible. I update the question again.

Comment: Ok. Finally code that demonstrates the problem. But as said before: works for me. Which Android version? You are using a real device?

Comment: No. Chat. Real device?

Comment: i tried on an other device and i don't have the same result. It is not working on a samsung GTab 12pce (Android 5.0.2) but it is working on a GTab 3 (android 7) ...

Comment: Tried on 5.0.2 device and all worked. You should have tried on other devices earlier!

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee `ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()` works for arbitrary `content:` URIs. The documentation contains the following warning:

> Open a raw file descriptor to access data under a URI. This is like openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri, String), but uses the underlying openFile(Uri, String) method, so will not work with providers that return sub-sections of files. If at all possible, you should use openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri, String). You will receive a FileNotFoundException exception if the provider returns a sub-section of a file.

For most use cases [ContentResolver.openInputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) is the preferable option.

Comment: same error after having replaced `openFileDescriptor` by `openInputStream` in my sample. I still got a `FileNotFoundException`